# Can't find module when running python script from another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

I have a simple script that utilizes flask.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    text = '<h2>Text: </h2><form><input name="firstname" type="text">'
    select = '<h2>Select: </h2><select name="cars">' + \
              '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>' + \
              '<option value="saab">Saab</option>' + \
              '<option value="fiat">Fiat</option> ' + \
              '<option value="audi">Audi</option>' + \
            '</select>'
    multiselect = '<h2>Multiselect: </h2><select name="mCars" multiple>' + \
              '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>' + \
              '<option value="saab">Saab</option>' + \
              '<option value="fiat">Fiat</option> ' + \
              '<option value="audi">Audi</option>' + \
            '</select>'
    textarea = '<h2>Textarea: </h2><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">' + \
                'The cat was playing in the garden.' + \
                '</textarea>'
    button = '<h2>Button</h2><button type="button" onclick="alert(\'Hello World!\')">Click Me!</button>'
    # datalist = '<h2>Datalist</h2><datalist id="browsers">' + \
    #               '<option value="Internet Explorer">' + \
    #               '<option value="Firefox">' + \
    #               '<option value="Chrome">' + \
    #               '<option value="Opera">' + \
    #               '<option value="Safari">' + \
    #             '</datalist> '
    return '<h1>Sample Form</h1>' + \
           text + \
           select + \
           multiselect + \
           textarea + \
           button


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Im trying to run it from another file called runner.py

```
subprocess.call(['python', get_driver_file_path(Settings.TestProjectPath)])
```

I am getting an error that it cant find the flask module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\Python\python-testing-framework\Fitv\FitvTests/TestProjects/Flask_App/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Flask is setup in the project though. If I simply run by right click > run in Pycharm it runs fine.

[image]

Why can't it find the module when running from another file?

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv in pycharm?

Comment: @rdas yes, see added screenshot.

Comment: Try changing the path of the executable in the `subprocess.call` to the full path of the executable of the virtualenv

Comment: Fixed. Thank you! I'll add pycharm to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to subprocess.sys.path or sys.path, where two are the same.

```py
subprocess.sys.path.append("your virtualenv path")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in pycharm.
Try below steps if you are using conda:-

1. First activate virtual env in anaconda prompt 
   conda activate virtual_env_name.
2. Navigate to the path where pycharm is installed.
3. Launch pycharm.

Above steps should resolve your problem.